# building C++ wrapper for QFS

Tags: c++, c, interface, wrapper, qfs

I am absolutely horrible with compiling/linking.

I have tried everything i could find, nothing works.

```
websockserver.h:516: undefined reference to `qfs_init'
websockserver.h:527: undefined reference to `qfs_read'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Rmdir(char const*)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Remove(char const*)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Open(char const*, int, int, int,         int, int, int, unsigned short, signed char, signed char)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Write(int, char const*, unsigned long)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Read(int, char*, unsigned long)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Rename(char const*, char const*, bool)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Tell(int)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Seek(int, long, int)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Stat(char const*, KFS::KfsFileAttr&, bool)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Close(int)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Create(char const*, int, bool, int, int, int, int, bool, unsigned short, signed char, signed char)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Sync(int)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::IsDirectory(char const*)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::ErrorCodeToStr(int)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::IsFile(char const*)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Exists(char const*)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Mkdir(char const*, unsigned short)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::KfsClient::Readdir(char const*, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)'
./cqfs//libcqfs.so: undefined reference to `KFS::Connect(std::string const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [w] Error 1
```

websockserver.h:514 to 530

```
long numbytes;
struct cqfs *qfs;
if(!qfs_init(&qfs, "127.0.0.1", 20000))
printf("Failed to init qfs connection\n");

int fd = qfs_open(qfs, "APP.js", O_RDONLY);
if(fd < 0)
    printf("Error opening file: %s\n", qfs_error(qfs));

numbytes = (long)qfs_seek(qfs, fd, 0L, SEEK_END);
qfs_seek(qfs, fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
ret = calloc(numbytes + 1, sizeof(char));

if(qfs_read(qfs, fd, ret, numbytes) < 0)
    printf("Error reading file: %s\n", qfs_error(qfs));

qfs_close(qfs, fd);
```

QFS provides .so and .a of
libqfs_client
libqfs_qcdio
libqfs_io
libqfs_common
libqfs_qcrs

How do i build my wrapper (cqfs.cpp, cqfs.h)?

This is my current command:

```
g++ -Wall -DBOOST_SP_USE_QUICK_ALLOCATOR -shared -o libcqfs.so cqfs.cpp cqfs.h -fPIC -L./libqfs_client.so -L./libqfs_qcdio.so -lpthread -lrt -L./libqfs_io.so -L./libqfs_common.so -L./libqfs_qcdio.so  -lpthread -lz -lrt -lboost_regex-mt -lcrypto -L./libqfs_qcrs.so -lc
```

based on the example application(not library) provided by Quantcast:

```
c++ -Wall -DBOOST_SP_USE_QUICK_ALLOCATOR -g    CMakeFiles/qfssample.dir/qfssample_main.o  -o qfssample -rdynamic ../../src/cc/libclient/libqfs_client.a ../../src/cc/qcdio/libqfs_qcdio.a -lpthread -lrt ../../src/cc/kfsio/libqfs_io.a ../../src/cc/common/libqfs_common.a ../../src/cc/qcdio/libqfs_qcdio.a -lpthread -lz -lrt -lboost_regex-mt -lcrypto ../../src/cc/qcrs/libqfs_qcrs.a
```

.a or .so did not make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are incorrectly using the -L argument to g++. The argument of -L should refer to the directory that contains the libraries, rather than directly referencing them.

To demonstrate, I created a simple example with a `Connect` and `Readdir` (I've omitted it for brevity, but let me know if you want to see it). Here is the `c++` command I crafted to get it to compile and link correctly:

```
c++ -Wall -o t -I./build/release/include -L./build/release/lib t.cc -lqfs_client -lqfs_common -lqfs_io -lqfs_qcdio -lqfs_qcrs -lpthread -lboost_regex-mt -lz -lcrypto
```

One can then run it by specifying the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Max OS X):

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/build/release/lib ./t
.
..
dumpster
test
test2
test3
user
```

Note that you'll have to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux.

We are actually working on building C bindings for QFS in the main project. Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/quantcast/qfs/pull/30). If you're not comfortable with working directly from the fork (they are *very* experimental), you can check it out and build with `make VERBOSE=1` to see the commands that are actually used to build the components and apply that to build your own bindings.

**UPDATE:** The C bindings for the QFS API are now available in the master branch.

For example, here is the line that is output to build the shared library on my mac:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -I/opt/local/include -Wall -DBOOST_SP_USE_QUICK_ALLOCATOR -O2 -g -shared   -o libqfsc.dylib -install_name /Users/sday/c/qfs/build/release/src/cc/qfsc/libqfsc.dylib CMakeFiles/qfsc-shared.dir/qfsc.o ../libclient/libqfs_client.dylib ../kfsio/libqfs_io.dylib ../common/libqfs_common.dylib -lpthread -lz ../qcdio/libqfs_qcdio.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib ../qcrs/libqfs_qcrs.dylib -lcrypto
```

Disclaimer: I work for Quantcast.

Comment: currently this is my makefile string
`g++ -Wall -DBOOST_SP_USE_QUICK_ALLOCATOR -shared -fPIC -o libcqfs.so cqfs.cpp cqfs.h libqfs_client.a libqfs_qcdio.a libqfs_io.a libqfs_common.a libqfs_qcdio.a libqfs_qcrs.a -lpthread -lrt -lz -lboost_regex-mt -lcrypto -lc`

Comment: my current wrapper implementation produces name mangling for a few functions no matter what, implemented is: `struct cqfs;
struct qfs_fileattr;
qfs_init (mangled)
qfs_read (mangled)
qfs_stat (mangled)
qfs_error
qfs_mkdir
qfs_rename
qfs_readdir
qfs_rmdir
qfs_create
qfs_open
qfs_close
qfs_seek
qfs_tell
qfs_write
qfs_sync
qfs_del
qfs_exists
qfs_isfile
qfs_isdir` I will take a look at your c bindings